# Problem on Cesaro mean

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if $\{s_n\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb C$ and $s_n \rightarrow s$ for $n \rightarrow +\infty$ then $\sigma_N=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} s_n \rightarrow s$ for $n \rightarrow +\infty$.

But is true also the converse?

Comment: $1,0,1,0,1,\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the inverse in general is not true. Take for example the sequence $a_n = (-1)^n $. The sequences that satisfy $ \cfrac{\sum_{k\leq n} a_k}{n} < \infty$ are called Cesàro summable.